# Php подключение файлов в зависимости от даты их создания

Tags: php, сортировка

Может вы подскажите куда копать. Дело в том, что у меня создается база токенов, по сути токен это .html файл. Потом в зависимости от даты, подключаются все токены из папки. Все работает отлично, но файлы подключаются в разнобой и это очень неудобно. Может вы поможете идеей, как сделать сортировку по дате создания файла, потом вывести все.

Файл php, который подключает и выводит токены файлы.

```
<?php

$date = $_REQUEST['date']; 
if($date == null or $date == ''){
    $date = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d");
}

   $dir = "/var/www/ob/data/www/ob/assets/files/security/ORDER_BASE/".str_replace('-','/',$date)."/";  
   $catalog = opendir($dir);

   while ($filename = readdir($catalog )) // перебираем наш каталог 
   {  
      $filename = $dir."/".$filename;  
      
      include_once($filename); // один раз подрубаем, чтоб не повторяться 
   
   }

   closedir($catalog);
 ?>
```

Comment: я вас удивлю, наверное, но вместое `date("Y") . '-'. date("m")` можно написать `date("Y-m-d")` а чтобы потом не заменять тире на слеши то сразу `date("Y/m/d")`

Comment: имена файлов как выглядят?

Comment: Имена совсем рандомные, выглядят примерно так: DONATION-6018802124435.html, DONATION-60188882b98ba.html, DONATION-601234482b98ba.html

Comment: сложность то в чем у вас? надо сначала читать директорию, получат дату создания файла. которую можно сделать ключом массива. Потом сортировать по ключам, а уже потом инклудить вторым циклом (не знаю, что там у вас внутри этих файлов и зачем это надо)

Comment: Сложность со знанием php. ). Спасибо за алгоритм, буду пробовать.